# Spring MVC: POST Request Json Object with list returns 400 bad request

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm getting a 400 BAD REQUEST error with my POST Request when I add an array to the JSON object.

MemberDTO.java

```
public class MemberDTO{
private String memberId;
private String purchaseDate;
private List<ProductDTO> selectedProductModels;
...
}
```

ProductDTO.java

```
public enum ProductDTO {
  PRODUCT1("Product 1", "12.00", "50%', "500.00"),
  PRODUCT2("Product 2", "120.00", "80%', "100.00");

  private String productName;
  private String discount;
  private String retailPrice;
  private String price;
....
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "member/purchase", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String purchase(@RequestBody MemberDTO data){
 ...
 }
```

JSON

```
var purchaseData = {
    "memberId" : "12312",
    "purchaseDate" : "2015/02/14",
    "selectedProductModels" : [{
         "productName" : "sample1",
         "discount": "10%",
         "retailPrice": "100.00",
         "price": "400.98"
     },{
         "productName" : "sample2",
         "discount": "20%",
         "retailPrice": "1400.00",
         "price": "4300.98"
     }]
};
```

Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : contextPath + "/member/purchase.do",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"application/json",
        data    : JSON.stringify(purchaseData),
        success : function(data) {}
});
```

I tried removing the "selectedProductModels" array list from json and I got successful response. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm sure if you look at the logs you will see an exception about not being able to create the enum. Use a custom deserializer or don't use an enum at all. It's an ugly looking enum anyway. And unless the company never offers any different products and different prices and discounts, you're better off just using a class.

Comment: @peeskillet i tried using other class instead of using that enum, i still get the same error when using an array. No exceptions. :(

Comment: Do you have the basic necessities for deserialization, no-arg constructor and proper setters?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to refer the Enumeration de-serialization options discussed here

[Jackson enum Serializing and DeSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468764/jackson-enum-serializing-and-deserializer)

[Serializing enums with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766791/serializing-enums-with-jackson)

[Converting JSON to Enum type with @RequestBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408083/converting-json-to-enum-type-with-requestbody)

You can specify the exact values "Product 1", "12.00", "50%", "500.00" specified in your Enum constants becuase only those values can be parsed, otherwise you have to write a custom JSON de-serializer

Note: "Product 1", "12.00", "50%', "500.00" there is a single quote in your text is that a type error?