# Write RequestBody for Restful method

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm a new member in Restful API, I'm writing a GET method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/resourcerecords", produces={"application/json", "application/xml"})
public @ResponseBody Object getRRs(@RequestBody RRRequest requestBody){
   // do something
}
```

The RRRequest class:

```
public class RRRequest{
   private RRREC reqObject;
   // getter and setter
}
```

The RRREC class:

```
public class RRREC{
   protected String infraAddr;
   protected RRINFRATYPE infraType;
   // getter and setter
}
```

And the RRINFRATYPE class:

```
public enum RRINFRATYPE {
    V_6_ADDRESS("V6ADDRESS"),
    OBJECT("OBJECT"),
    ZONE("ZONE"),
    V_4_REVERSEZONE("V4REVERSEZONE"),
    V_6_REVERSEZONE("V6REVERSEZONE"),
    NODE("NODE"),
    ALL("ALL");
    private final String value;

    RRINFRATYPE(String v) {
       value = v;
   }

   public String value() {
      return value;
   }

   public static RRINFRATYPE fromValue(String v) {
     for (RRINFRATYPE c: RRINFRATYPE.values()) {
        if (c.value.equals(v)) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
}
```

Then, I sent a request GET with RequestBody ( I use Fiddler Web Debugger)

```
"reqObject" : {    
   "infraAddr" : "192.168.88.4",
   "infraType": {
       "value": "OBJECT"
   }
}
```

I get 400 Bad Request. If I change to

```
 "reqObject" : {    
   "infraAddr" : "192.168.88.4",
   "InfraType": {
       "value": "OBJECT"
   }
}
```

I can debug.

However, The reqObject only receive `infraAddr` with "192.168.88.4", the `InfraType` is null.

Who can explain to me, why I must be use `"InfraType"` instead of `"infraType"` and how to send value for `InfraType`.

Comment: You mustn't, you don't have such property.

Comment: you request is GET you cannot have `@RequestBody`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is when your api in GET method you still cant send body of request to server, try to change it to POST.

Because you use `ENUM` in your Object so you should define a converter like [Converting JSON to Enum type with @RequestBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408083/converting-json-to-enum-type-with-requestbody)

But in this case, I think the fastest way is change `infraType` to `String` and use switch case with String on server side.

```
public class RRREC{
   protected String infraAddr;
   protected String infraType;
   // getter and setter
}
```

Your JSON will be:

```
{
    "reqObject" : {    
        "infraAddr" : "192.168.88.4",
        "infraType": "OBJECT"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I had to change to POST, however InfraType still null

Comment: If I use "infraType" in JSON, I get an error 404 Bad Request

Comment: no just change it into String and its value be like overthere.